# Quickest way to move files between two external drives

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I am aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1115751/whats-the-fastest-way-to-transfer-data-between-two-hard-drives), and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/120251/how-to-increase-the-speed-between-two-external-hard-drives-on-my-laptop), but my circumstances are different as I do not have a USB hub.

I have two USB 3 external hard-drives, one 4tB  and one 8gB and a laptop with two USB 3 ports. I have no USB hub.

Would transfer (move, not copy) be quicker if I :

1. connect both hard-drives to the laptop and move files between them
2. connect one drive, move files from it to the laptop, then from there to the other hard-drive

Let us assume that I have enough space on the laptop to do 2) in one pass, If not, I can live with doing it in multiple operations.

The laptop has an i7 processors with 16gB RAM - would it be best to close all apps while moving?  I would prefer not to, obviously.

The laptopalso has an internal SSD, but there is only about 50gB free there; I note this, because it might speed up option 2 if done in multiple passes.

While I am looking for a solution to suit my own configuration, feel free to help others by additionally mentioning the generic case of two drives & one PC, with no mention of processor type, amount of RAM, SSD drive, etc

Comment: it should REALLY be faster to copy things directly from one drive to the other. Even if the individual operation is slightly slower, you will gain time simply by only having to do one file transfer instead of two.

Comment: This is trivial to benchmark ...

Comment: have you benchmarked it? Or can you point me at someone who has?

Comment: @Mawg, you have your specific drives, you have your specific laptop, why do you ask anyone else to run benchmarks for you?

Comment: Where did I ask anyone to run benchmarks? Indeed, I also welcomed a generic solution. I just expected a generic "if all of your drives are USB.x and you have two free USB.x ports then ... either 1) or 2) is better",with, perhaps, some mention of the SSD drive in my own case.

Comment: Mawg, transfer a test set of files multiple ways and measure.  Then do the entire transfer the fastest way.  To many, this would be a "trivial benchmark"  Not a scientific benchmark, but something that should give you an idea of "better than the other".  And I would copy, verify, delete.  NOT move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect both drives and move from one to the other.

But, don't use Windows file Explorer to do it.  Use **anything** else.  TeraCopy (most popular on Lifehacker), FastCopy, CopyHandler, Robocopy,  UltraCopier, UnstoppableCopier.  I've used used SuperCopier on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning to your suggestions? :)

Comment: @bertieb, I've found Windows 7 and 10 file explorer file transfers to be slow compared to SuperCopier (win7) and TeraCopy (Win10), for large transfers (hundreds of MBytes, tens or hundreds of files, or both).  
    
The list was the results of searching Google for "windows file copy utility" plus my comments on the two I've used.

Comment: If you have reasons to recommend one over the other - like speed you mentioned - that information is worth including in the answer

Comment: I can certainly agree with TeraCopy. I have been using it happily for a few years now, and comparative reviews posted online make it clear that it is superior.

Comment: The `/mt` ([multi-threaded parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)) for `Robocopy` is worth mentioning as a huge reason for using it over File Explorer, right?